# Why is spinlock no-op in Linux kernel (non-SMP)?

Tags: linux, kernel, spinlock

I've been reading this for quite some time but doesn't make sense to me.. Probably because I'm new to all this and still don't understand few kernel concepts.

This was what i came up with (no error or NULL handing, it's just for the sake of the question):

Kernel spinlocks are executed inside kernel threads, which is preemtive.

```
void spinlock_acquire(spinlock_t *spinlock)
{
  tryagain:
    while(spinlock->plock != UNLOCKED) ;
    context_switch_block;
    if(spinlock->plock != UNLOCKED) {
        context_switch_unblock;
        goto tryagain;
    }
    spinlock_lock(spinlock, current_thread);
    context_switch_unblock;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Or at least I don't understand how the code you included is related to the question.

Comment: spinlock on a single CPU, what is wrong in the code ?

I've read that in Linux on single CPU, spinlock code is rather equivalent to no op, but why ?

Comment: Totally dont understand your code....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before Linux was a preemptive kernel, spinlocks on UP were basically no-ops. Once the kernel was made preemptive, a call to `preempt_disable()` was added to spinlocks.

So it goes more or less like this:

- You want to protect against some conflicting CPU, use some kind of spinlock.
- You want to protect against a conflicting softirq, tasklet,... use `spin_lock_bh`, which disables softirqs, tasklets, etc... (`bh` is for historical name, it comes from "bottom half").
- You want to protect against a conflicting hardware interrupt use `spin_lock_irq*`, which disables hardware interrupts.
- All spinlocks protect against preemption.
- On a UP kernel, spinlocks don't take a real spinlock (since there are no conflicting CPUs, and we cannot be preempted, and there are spinlock variants for dealing with hardirqs, softirqs,...).
- On a UP machine with an SMP kernel, spinlocks may be turned into nops.
- Even on a UP kernel with preemption disabled, spinlocks may have code for spinlock debugging, if it is enabled.

Comment: Pretty much the most satisfying answer, upvoted. But why spinlocks are used only to protect against conflicting CPUs ? Shouldn't it be used in any place to protect against multiple thread hazard just like mutexes ? Isn't the only difference in mutex and spinlock the fact that mutex blocks the thread till availability and spinlock spins till availability ? Will select this as answer once this is cleared.

Comment: Yeah, right. I expressed it badly. That is covered by point 4: all spinlocks protect against preemption, by virtue of the `preempt_disable()` call. Recall that the only hazards you can have are other CPUs, interrupts (NMIs, hardirqs, softirqs, tasklets,...), and other kernel threads that preempt your own code. Covered by first four bullet points.

Comment: Thanks for your time however, could you please explain how if the example code in the question is wrong ?

Comment: @user1075375: I don't know where did you get that example from, but it's not from the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Spin lock is unnecessary on non-SMP. Since a spin lock disabled interrupts, it is not possible to anyone else to have the lock at that point. Once thread A disabled interrupts, is is not possible for thread B to try and acquire the same lock, as there is nothing that can cause A to lose the CPU in favor of B. As such, all spin lock does on non-SMP is, well, nothing (except if you ask it to disable interrupts).

Shachar

Comment: Why would spinlock disable interrupts ?

Comment: @user1075375: plain spinlocks don't disable interrupts, `spin_lock_irq*` disable local interrupts, they are to be used when you have a conflicting interrupt handler, which would use a normal spinlock in turn.

Comment: @user1075375: spin lock must be run with interrupts disabled on the local CPU. The spin lock itself does not have to disable the interrupts itself, if those are already disabled. It is up to the program, then, to make sure no code **can** run that will try to acquire the lock while it's held.

Comment: I don't understand you Shachar, suppose i know that i need one of the mutually shared resource for a very small time, like writing a 32 bit register or setting a flag in ram, i can use spinlock instead of mutex because mutex would cause my thread to yield if lock isn't available and context switches are very resource consuming so i end up wasting my cpu resources on ejecting the thread when i could have obtained the lock in a few cycles. Oh okay, i think i got the point, it won't be a few cycles since there's only one CPU and there needs to be a context switch to free the lock... Thanks.

Comment: but even then, what's the need to block interrupts while holding a spinlock ?

Comment: If you do not block interrupts, then an interrupt handler might need the same critical section while you're holding the lock. There is no way to resolve this problem, as until that handler returns, you cannot finish your critical section handling. This is not a problems for mutexes, because you are not allowed to acquire them inside an interrupt handler.